# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3' - Android apk

Tags: python, android, requests, компиляция, apk

Пытался сделать приложение под андроид с помощью **Python/Kivy**.

Тестовый **"Hello World"** запустился (Также запускаются и другие приложения **без** использования библиотек связанных с парсингом).

НО как только пытаюсь подключить requests/BeatifulSoup4 программа крашится и логи выдают ошибку:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'**

Пытался импортировать urllib3 в **.spec** и **.py** файл - не помогает.

Подскажите, что делать в таком случае?

P.S. Для сборки .apk использую google colab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651145/no-module-named-urllib3

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja , спасибо, уже просматривал это статью, не помогло

Comment: Так добавьте это в вопрос - что делали и что получилось в результате.

Answer (score 0):

Colab может не подтянуть все нужные библиотеки.

Лучше на Windows установить эмулятор WSL и там уже скомпилировать apk-файл (или aab, если в планах загружать в тот же Google Play).